# How can I add an event for a one time click to a function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a click event listener to a function but would only like it to happen once. How could i do this?

I would like to stay clear of JQuery as well if it is possible please.

EDITED

As the answers that I am getting for this are fully satisfying my need i thought i may make it a bit more clear with context.

I am writing a function to draw a rectangle, first with one click on a button to initiate the rectangle function. Then there are two click event listeners in the drawRectangle function. These are the events i would like to happen only once in the function. Allowing the user to then create another rectangle if they click on the rectangle initiation button again.

Comment: @antyrat OP specifically asked for no jQuery.

Comment: Wouldn't setting a boolean to `false` on start and then do an `if` if it's the first time, and if it is indeed the first time change it to `true`?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

## Use modern JavaScript!

```
EventTarget.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Do something cool

}, {once : true});
```

> A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If `true`, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)

[All modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener) support this feature

[Other reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once)

Comment: Still cannot be used for most production sites because it has no IE11 support. But very nice indeed!

Answer (score 20):

You have to use `removeEventListener` once the event is fired once. However, `removeEventListener` takes a function as argument, which means you need to declare a named function, add it with `addEventListener`, and have it removing itself. Example:

```
function foo() {
    // do things, then
    removeEventListener('click', foo);
}

addEventListener('click', foo);
```

Comment: I forgot about this initially too, but `removeEventListener` needs the event type too: `removeEventListener("click", foo);`

Comment: wait wait, `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` are both methods not functions!

Comment: This is a deprecated solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291530/2826713

Comment: @amatyas001 this is NOT deprecated. it's a valid answer with no deprecated code and sometimes the best you can do e.g. for a conditional one time listener

Answer (score 3):

```
function one(el, type, fn) {
    function handler(event) {
        el.removeEventListener(type, handler);
        fn(event);
    }
    el.addEventListener(type, handler);
}

// use it like
one(window, 'resize', function () {
    alert("This triggers just once");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6njpem7x/

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct in that this can be achieved with a named function, but you don't need to declare the function separately. You can use a *named function expression*:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function handler(event) {
  this.removeEventListener("click", handler);
  // ...
});
```

An alternative, though less optimal, approach is to keep around a variable that keeps track whether the handler was executed:

```
var wasExecuted = false;
element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (wasExecuted) {
    return;
  }
  wasExecuted = true;
  // ...
});
```

The variable needs to be declared outside the handler but within scope, so that its value persists across event triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener):

```
element.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
function clickFunction(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
    element.removeEventListener("click", clickFunction);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eusccj9m/)

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain what i wish to achieve fully. I would like to call a function using a click event. and then within this i would like to have two click functions that work only once. for that function call.

To put it into context, I am writing a function to draw an SVG rectangle. The two one time clicks are for getting the points on the canvas of the corners of the rectangle and the overall function is the one to draw the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
var el = document.getElementById('something');
el.addEventListener('click', doSomething);

function doSomething() {
  el.removeEventListener('click', doSomething);

  //code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside event handler you can use universal: `e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee)`
Or you can make special function for creating "one time" event listeners:

```
function oneTimeListener(node, type, callback) {
    // create event
    node.addEventListener(type, function(e) {
        // remove event listener
        e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
        // call handler with original context 
        // as it happens with native addEventListener
        return callback.call(this, e); 
    });
}

oneTimeListener(document.getElementById("myElement"), "click", myHandler);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set a cookie after first click:

```
document.cookie="click=1; expires=.......";
```

and add condition to listener - if cookie is set, you omit that.

Comment: I don't believe that's actually what the OP wanted. He said he was using the `click` event listener, not cookies.

Comment: Taking the one click thing *very* literally there, I like it!

Comment: @RGraham that's why I added "expires" - besides the cookie can be deleted anywhere else in the code if that click is required to function again.

Comment: @n-dru Absolutely! I'm saying you might be right in saying that the OP doesn't want the user to be able to click that element on subsequent visits.

Comment: But it's actually a totally valid answer, a bit over-engineered but works, huh?

Answer (score -2):

Another simple solution which I'm using is to add a dummy class to the element to which we are listening so that it will not fire again.

```
const myButton = document.querySelector('#my-button:not(.init)');
myButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     myButton.classList.add('init');
  });
```