# Can I add onmouseover attribute to run only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover

Say I have a link like the following:

`<a class="link" href="www.rich.com" onmouseover="go(this)">Link</a>`

Is there a way to configure the `onmouseover` event, calling `go(this)` to run only a single time *while still using the inline `onmouseover=<some code>` notation?* **I want it defined inline, not with a JavaScript call.**

Currently, I have this, but it is not what I want:

```
$(".link").one('mouseover', function(e) {
     // do something
});
```

Comment: You need to be a little more clear by what you mean only run once. Run once, literally. Run once per hover. Run once per .link ? Because .one should work.

Comment: @Mark run once literally. Like using `one()`.

Comment: Just curious - why do you prefer to do it this way?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I want to do it this way because I rebuild links via AJAX calls and by doing it inline I don't have to have random function calls all over the code one the link is created and inserted into the DOM. Instead, I can "bind" an event handler when in only one place -- when I format the HTML string at the very beginning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can nullify the `onmouseover` binding afterwards:

```
<a class="link" href="www.rich.com" onmouseover="go(this); this.onmouseover = null;">Link</a>
```

Comment: Great answer. This is much cleaner then alternatives.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: How do I re-enable onmouseover when `onmouseout`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Vanilla JS:

```
const link = document.querySelector('.link');
link.addEventListener('mouseover',
  () = window.open('your url'),
  { once : true }
);
```

ref: [How can I add an event for a one time click to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610365/how-can-i-add-an-event-for-a-one-time-click-to-a-function)

Answer (score -1):

You could set a var that indicates whether it has been triggered or not...

```
var triggered = false;

$(".link").one('mouseover', function(e) {
     // do something
     if(!triggered)
     {
        triggered = true;

        // and whatever else you want to do 
     }

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you can do something like this :

```
var check = 0;
$(".link").on('mouseover', function(e) {
    if(check == 0 ){
       // do something
       check = 1;
    }else {
       return false;
    }
});
```