# Translating .one and .on events from JQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, equivalent

I found this piece of code to manage the he¡ght from textareas:

```
// Applied globally on all textareas with the "autoExpand" class
$(document)
    .one('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

It comes from this link: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD

I would like to translate these lines to the JavaScript version.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610365/how-can-i-add-an-event-for-a-one-time-click-to-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `.autoExpand` from `focus.autoExpand` or `input.autoExpand` because it's not valid event and try this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('textarea.autoExpand').forEach(function(item) {
  // .one
  item.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    console.log('called once')
    var savedValue = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
    this.value = savedValue;
    // remove event after called once
    item.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    // e.type is current event or "focus"
    // arguments.callee is current callback function
  })
  // .on
  item.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows') | 0, rows;
    this.rows = minRows;
    rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
    this.rows = minRows + rows;
  })
})
```