# Bootstrap event "shown.bs.modal" fires multiple times everytime I click the toggle button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap5-modal

I am building a pdf view with PDF.js to render pdf inside bootstrap modal, and according to the documentation I can listen to "shown.bs.modal" event when the modal popup is displayed so I have this code:

```
function renderPdfMobile() {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    doc.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      const file = e.target.dataset.file;

      var modal = document.getElementById("fileModal");
      modal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {

      

      console.log(modal)

      })

    })

  })
}

renderPdfMobile()
```

Code works every time I click the modal button. The problem is it fires with the increment of +1 every time.

So in console
When I click once, I get `"fired"`
when I click again I get

```
"fired"
"fired"
```

another click results in:

```
"fired"
"fired"
"fired"
```

At this point, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

*EDITED*

Comment: Exactly where in the rest of your code do those lines you posted appear? Is it possible that the code is inside *another* event listener?

Comment: The point is that `.addEventListener()` **adds** a listener: it does not remove other event listeners that may already have been added. If you add the same listener function multiple times, it will be called multiple times.

Comment: Added the function.

Comment: OK, exactly as I commented earlier. Every "click" event **adds** another event listener. All the event listeners will be called when "shown.bs.modal" fires. To fix the problem, don't add another event listener on every "click".

Comment: You were right! I removed it from the loop, and now I am no longer getting the bug. Thanks.

Comment: There is a solution for this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610365/how-can-i-add-an-event-for-a-one-time-click-to-a-function